# cartesian product of integral $A$-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Given two $A$-algebras $B_1$ and $B_2$ by the homomorphisms $f_i: A \to B_i$. Suppose that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are integral $A$-algebras. Then $B:=B_1\times B_2$ is an $A$-algebra by $f(a)=(f_1(a),f_2(a))$. How to show that $B$ is an integral $A$-algebra?

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Did you try checking the definition of integral?

Comment: yes, by the definition we have $g_1,g_2\in A[x]$ such that $g_1(b_1)=0$ and $g_2(b_2)=0$. But how do we get a $g\in A[x], g(x)=d_0+d_1x+...+d_{k-1}x^{k-1}+x^{k}$ such that $f(d_0)+f(d_1)(b_1,b_2)+...+f(d_{k-1})(b_1,b_2)^{k-1}+(b_1,b_2)^{k}=0$?

Comment: Try $g_1\cdot g_2$?

Comment: Oh my... I was thinking way too difficult... Thanks!